# How do I locate files with glob lib in Python and print them

Tags: python, glob

Please tell me what is wrong here, I've been digging the internet over 3 days and can't find the solution.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob

folder_name = input("Please insert the folder name to locate databases: ")
diskD = glob.glob("D:/*/{folder_name}/*.*".format, root_dir="D:", dir_fd=1, recursive=True)
inFilesD = glob.glob(diskD)
print(os.path.basename(inFilesD))
```

I tried changing multiple lines, HOPING for program to locate a specific folder and print out it's content/files

Comment: For one thing, you're not actually calling the string `.format()` function, because you've left off the parentheses `()` at the end.

Comment: Secondly, if you fix that, `diskD` would be a list of pathnames, which you can't pass to another `glob.glob()` call.

Comment: Thirdly, `os.path.basename()` does not accept a list of filepaths.

Comment: You don't need `.format`. Put `f` before the string to make it an f-string that automatically substitutes the variable.

Comment: `recursive=True` is meaningless unless the argument contains `**` as a directory name.

Comment: `dir_fd=1` and `root_dir="D:"` are meaningless when the pathname argument is absolute. It also makes no sense to use both of them, I'm not sure what happens if you do, since both of them specify how relative paths should be interpreted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an f-string to format the pathname. Use `**` for the directory to search all folders.

There's no need to call `glob.glob()` twice, the first one already returned all the filenames.

Loop over all the results, calling `os.path.basename()` on each of them; you can't call it on the list directly.

```
folder_name = input("Please insert the folder name to locate databases: ")
diskD = glob.glob(f"D:/**/{folder_name}/*.*", recursive=True)
for file in diskD:
    print(os.path.basename(file))
```